# Alterar valores do google chart ao clicar em um elemento

Tags: javascript, google-charts

Preciso alterar os valores do gráfico de dias para meses e vice-versa ao clicar nos "botões" `por dia/por mês`, já tentei criar dois gráficos e usar `hide();` e `show();` ao clicar, quase deu certo, porem ao clicar no botão o gráfico que estava com `display:none` aparece bem pequeno diferente do que carregou junto com a pagina.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Chart by day
  google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
   var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
   data.addColumn('number', 'Day');
   data.addColumn('number', 'Tempo');
   data.addColumn('number', 'Tempo');

   data.addRows([
    [1,  5, 7],
    [2,  10, 5],
    [3,  7,  9],
    [4,  10,  15],
    [5,  5,  5]
    ]);


   var options = {
    title: '',
    hAxis: {
     title: '',
     format: '# março'
    },
    vAxis: {
     minValue: 0,
     ticks: [5, 10, 15, 20],
     format: '# min.'
    },
    legend: {position: 'none'},
    chartArea:{top:'15',width:'90%',height:'80%'},
    series: {
     0: { color: '#0b82c6' },
     1: { color: '#8fb809' },
    },
    lineWidth: 3
   };

   var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart-performed'));
   chart.draw(data, options);
  }


  $('.dia-mes span:last-child').on('click', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $('.dia-mes span:first-child').removeClass('green');
   $('.dia-mes span:last-child').addClass('green')

  });
  $('.dia-mes span:first-child').on('click', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $('.dia-mes span:last-child').removeClass('green');
   $('.dia-mes span:first-child').addClass('green')
  });
 });
```

```css
.chart-performed h3
 {
  margin: 45px 0 15px 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #7f8c8d;
  font-weight:500;
 }
 #chart-performed,
 #chart-performed svg,
 #chart-performed div div
 {
  height:270px !important;
 }
 #chart-performed-month,
 #chart-performed-month svg,
 #chart-performed-month div div
 {
  height:270px !important;
 }
 .chart-label
 {
  margin:0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 25px 60px 25px 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:flex-start;
  flex-direction:row;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:space-between;
 }
 .label
 {
    display: flex;
 }
 .chart-label .label > span
 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  align-items:center;
  margin-right:50px;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:600;
  color:#666464;
 }
 .chart-label .label > span:first-child::before
 {
  background-color:#0b82c6;
 }
 .chart-label .label > span:last-child::before
 {
  background-color:#8fb809;
 }
 .chart-label .label > span::before
 {
  content:'';
  width:14px;
  height:14px;
  border-radius:100%;
  display:block;
  margin-right: 5px;
 }
 .chart-label .dia-mes
 {
  text-align: right;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 2px solid #bcbdbe;
  display:flex;
 }
 .chart-label .dia-mes span
 {
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:500;
  color:#bcbdbe;
  padding:3px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
 .chart-label .dia-mes .green
 {
  background-color: #8fb809;
  color:#fff;
  border-radius:5px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div class="chart-performed">
 <h3>Atividades realizadas x Quizes respondidos</h3>
 <div class="chart-label">
  <div class="label">
   <span>Atividades</span>
   <span>Quizes</span>
  </div>
  <div class="dia-mes">
   <span class="green">por dia</span>
   <span>por mês</span>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="chart-performed" style="width: 100%;"></div>
 <div id="chart-performed-month" style="width: 100%;"></div>
</div>
```

Quando uso o hide(); e show(); como disse acima, acontece isso aqui:

[image: Carrega junto com a pagina]

[image: Carrega após clicar no botão]

Comment: Não sei se entendi muito bem. Suas duas imagens mostram os dados de 1 mês específico (março e abril). Você gostaria de alternar o mês ou **por mês** seria separado por mês (janeiro, fevereiro, março, abril...)?

Comment: @Randrade  desculpe esqueci de mencionar a imagem não esta correta, na vdd uma deve mostrar por dia exemplo 1 março, 2 março, 3 março e a outra deve estar o acumulado do mês  março, abril, maio e por ai vai ...  Na imagem eu so quis mostrar o que acontece quando tento usar dois graficos deixando um com display none e alterando para block quando clico no elemento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não entendi muito bem como você popula esses dados, se vem de um WS, ou se está manual. Por isso, criei duas funções, uma para popular por dia e outra por mês.

Ao clicar nos botões, basta chamar a função para popular novamente o gráfico, como no exemplo abaixo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Chart by day
  google.charts.load("current", {
    packages: ["corechart"]
  });
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  var chart;

  function drawChartMonth() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Mes');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Tempo');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Tempo');

    data.addRows([
      ['Jan', 25, 7],
      ['Fev', 30, 5],
      ['Mar', 72, 9],
      ['Abr', 60, 15],
      ['Mai', 5, 5]
    ]);


    var options = {
      title: '',
      vAxis: {
        minValue: 0,
        ticks: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80],
        format: '# min.'
      },
      legend: {
        position: 'none'
      },
      chartArea: {
        top: '15',
        width: '90%',
        height: '80%'
      },
      series: {
        0: {
          color: '#0b82c6'
        },
        1: {
          color: '#8fb809'
        },
      },
      lineWidth: 3
    };

    chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart-performed'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }

  function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'Day');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Tempo');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Tempo');

    data.addRows([
      [1, 5, 7],
      [2, 10, 5],
      [3, 7, 9],
      [4, 10, 15],
      [5, 5, 5]
    ]);


    var options = {
      title: '',
      hAxis: {
        title: '',
        format: '# março'
      },
      vAxis: {
        minValue: 0,
        ticks: [5, 10, 15, 20],
        format: '# min.'
      },
      legend: {
        position: 'none'
      },
      chartArea: {
        top: '15',
        width: '90%',
        height: '80%'
      },
      series: {
        0: {
          color: '#0b82c6'
        },
        1: {
          color: '#8fb809'
        },
      },
      lineWidth: 3
    };

    chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart-performed'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }


  $('.dia-mes span:last-child').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.dia-mes span:first-child').removeClass('green');
    $('.dia-mes span:last-child').addClass('green')
    drawChartMonth();
  });
  $('.dia-mes span:first-child').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.dia-mes span:last-child').removeClass('green');
    $('.dia-mes span:first-child').addClass('green')
    drawChart();
  });
});
```

```css
.chart-performed h3 {
  margin: 45px 0 15px 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #7f8c8d;
  font-weight: 500;
}

#chart-performed,
#chart-performed svg,
#chart-performed div div {
  height: 270px !important;
}

#chart-performed-month,
#chart-performed-month svg,
#chart-performed-month div div {
  height: 270px !important;
}

.chart-label {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 25px 60px 25px 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.label {
  display: flex;
}

.chart-label .label>span {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 50px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #666464;
}

.chart-label .label>span:first-child::before {
  background-color: #0b82c6;
}

.chart-label .label>span:last-child::before {
  background-color: #8fb809;
}

.chart-label .label>span::before {
  content: '';
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.chart-label .dia-mes {
  text-align: right;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 2px solid #bcbdbe;
  display: flex;
}

.chart-label .dia-mes span {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #bcbdbe;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.chart-label .dia-mes .green {
  background-color: #8fb809;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div class="chart-performed">
  <h3>Atividades realizadas x Quizes respondidos</h3>
  <div class="chart-label">
    <div class="label">
      <span>Atividades</span>
      <span>Quizes</span>
    </div>
    <div class="dia-mes">
      <span class="green">por dia</span>
      <span>por mês</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="chart-performed" style="width: 100%;"></div>
</div>
```

Devo ressaltar também, que o Google Chart possui uma opção de 
[Controls and Dashboards](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls), que pode ser que te ajude também.

Comment: Cara muito obrigado pela ajuda, era isso mesmo, agora vou fuçar mais no código e deixar do jeito que preciso, vlw.

Comment: Sem problemas. Se precisar de algo, basta avisar.